# UbuntuStudio installer does not allow partition resize?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I'm running FC18 + virtualbox and trying to install Ub.Studio 12.10 64bit. It works "fine" as live CD (except jackd, the main audio server, isn't working.. supposedly there is a fix for this) but when trying to install it I have problems..

The installer demands 8.5GB of disk space. I gave it 12GB thru VirtualBox (allocating as needed; not all up front). Yet without custom partitioning (ie clicking 'Something else') it halts shortly into the installation, saying there is not enough space.

When the partition dialogue comes up, if I select the device (here, /dev/sda) and click 'New partition table...' I'm not allowed to modify it b/c it is 'In use by LVM volume group ubuntu-studio.' I cannot change the sizes of, or delete/add partitions, as the plus/minus keys are grayed out. All I can change are partition formats, whether partition is formatted, and its mount point.

So, in order to get the installer to work, I had to switch the home, root, and swap volumes, as that was the only thing the installer would let me do.

Now I have an ~8gb root volume, ~4gb home volume, and a ~255mb swap space. It's actually not bad for my purposes, but it sure would be nice if I could, myself, change the sizes of each partition at install time..

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why bother to make separate partitions if you are running Virtualbox? If you let the Ubuntu-installer make the decision, it will make one partition of 12 gb, and then you don't have the split problem.